# How to add directory name as a prefix to files starting with a specific pattern?

Tags: bash, shell

I had 1000 directories with different names, but the files in all those directories has a files starting with `tran-20.ft`, `tran-30.ft`, `tran-40.ft`, `tran-50.ft`, `tran-60.ft`.

Directory structure

```
dir1 ---tran-20.ft
  :     tran-30.ft
  :     tran-40.ft
  :     tran-50.ft
  :     tran-60.ft
  :
dir1000
```

Expected output

```
dir1 --- dir1_tran-20.ft
         dir1_tran-30.ft
         dir1_tran-40.ft
         dir1_tran-50.ft
         dir1_tran-60.ft
```

I'd like to add directory name as a prefix to specific files(`tran*`) only? How I do that?

Comment: I tried it's not working. But it shows in echo ? result file remains same, no prefix added to files.

Comment: It working, I executed wrong script.Thanks @Gilles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this with [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) *parameter expansions*:

```
for f in */tran-*.ft; do
    echo mv "$f" "${f%%/*}/${f%%/*}_${f##*/}"
done
```

Remove the `echo` when outputs looks good enough

---

Or like this with [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

```
rename -n 's!^([^/]+)/(tran-\d+\.ft)!$1/${1}_$2!' */tran-*.ft
```

Remove the `-n` switch when outputs looks good enough

Comment: I tried it's not working. But it shows in echo ? result file remains same, no prefix added to files.

Comment: Did you read what I wrote ? **Remove the `echo` when outputs looks good enough**

Comment: Sorry @ Gilles I confused my self, It working. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *pure shell*? The second command looks *purer* shell style as it does one invocation of  the appropriate command for the task while the first one runs many invocations of `mv` in a loop.

Comment: Maybe 'simple' would be more appropriate than 'pure'. Anyway, removed this mention. I know `rename` is better, but many times I show this, the OP don't understand or don't want to install 'external tools' and prefer what he whows better, like my first snippet. That's why I show both methods