# What are the different versions of the rename command? How do I use the Perl version?

Tags: regular-expression, perl, rename

This is a mess. How do I know which command to use when we expect Perl's rename with `s///` sed-like syntax, when there're tons of different implementations of `rename`, that are different versions of the Perl one or most of the time `rename.ul` (binary)?

Comment: Dropping a comment here so the two questions are linked: [What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230)

Comment: Linked together, here I go more _in depth_. Thanks for reporting

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Perl's `rename`

The most well-known and intuitive tool for bulk renaming files is Perl's `rename`. It is pretty much like `sed` on steroids (but meant for renaming files).

### TL;DR

If you want to use it the expected way, better use Perl's CPAN to install the expected version. There's too many versions out there.

See "Generic Perl CPAN install" below.

### Usage (`sed` `s///` like)

It's able to do powerful regex processing:

```
rename [options] 's/<regex>/<replacement>/[modifiers]' <FILE(S)>[*]
<STDIN> | rename [options] 's/<regex>/<replacement>/[modifiers]'
```

### Examples

- If you want to add spaces between each word of an mp4 filename in `TitleCase` ([`PascalCase`](https://betterprogramming.pub/string-case-styles-camel-pascal-snake-and-kebab-case-981407998841) to *Words Separated By Spaces*):

  ```
  rename -n 's/\B[[:upper:]]/ $&/g' ./*.mp4
  rename(./FooBarBaz.mp4, ./Foo Bar Baz.mp4)
  ```

  Remove `-n` switch, aka `dry-run` when your attempts are satisfactory **to rename for real**.
- you even can inject calls in the `replacement` part, like `sprintf "%03d", 7` zero padding with the `e` modifier:

  ```
  $ touch {1..3}.txt
  $ rename -n 's/(\d+)\.txt/sprintf "%03d", $1/e' ./*.txt
  rename(1.txt, 001.txt)
  rename(2.txt, 002.txt)
  rename(3.txt, 003.txt)
  ```
- reverse order of text separated by `-` using [*capture group*](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Capture-groups):

  ```
  $ rename -n 's/(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)/$3-$2-$1/' ./foo-bar-base.txt
  rename(foo-bar-base.txt, base-bar-foo.txt)
  ```

  or using `Perl`ish way ([TMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)):

  ```
  $ rename -n 's/(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)  # capture groups
                /join "-", reverse @{^CAPTURE}/xe' foo-bar-base.txt
  rename(foo-bar-base.txt, base-bar-foo.txt)
  ```

[You (Wo|Do)n’t Learn Perl in Five Minutes](https://web.archive.org/web/20221023012752/www.howtogeek.com/423214/how-to-use-the-rename-command-on-linux/)

> Getting to grips with Perl is time well spent. But to start using the time-saving capabilities of the rename command, you don’t need to have much Perl knowledge at all to reap large benefits in power, simplicity and time.

### Check your own version

[image: note] **There's another binary tool with the same name used on some distro. Depending on your distro, the Perl version can be called `perl-rename`, `file-rename`, `prename`, [`pname`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/162236) or `rename`.**
There's also a [Python `rename`](https://pypi.org/project/rename/) command out there !

```
rename --version
```

should look like this:

```
/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 1.30, File::Rename::Options version 1.10
```

or on old versions:

```
Unknown option: help
Usage: rename [-v] [-n] [-f] perlexpr [filenames
```

Or

```
rename 2>&1 | grep -i perl
    [ -e|-E perlexpr]*|perlexpr [ files ]
```

**And not something using** `rename` from `util-linux`

#### Table of default versions VS distros of rename command

Borrowed from [this comment on tldr-pages's GitHub issue tracker by @mebeim](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr/issues/3125#issuecomment-504798216):

> |  | Perl (old) | Perl (new) | Perl (other?) | C |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Linux (Debian) | prename (pkg perl), deprecated | file‑rename (pkg rename) | N/A | rename.ul (pkg util-linux) |
> | Linux (Ubuntu) | N/A | file‑rename (pkg rename) | N/A | rename.ul (pkg util-linux) |
> | Linux (Arch) | N/A | N/A | perl‑rename (pkg perl-rename) | rename (pkg util-linux) |
> | Linux (CentOS, RHEL) | N/A | N/A | N/A | rename (pkg util-linux) |
> | Linux (Fedora) | N/A | N/A | prename (pkg prename) | rename (pkg util-linux) |
> | Linux (openSUSE) | N/A | N/A | N/A | rename (pkg util-linux) |
> | macOS (Homebrew) | N/A | N/A | rename (pkg rename) | rename (pkg util-linux) |
> | Windows | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A |
> | Solaris | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A |

##### Important notes:

- on Windows, `rename` is a completely different command (therefore I did not list it above), but can be used as well, check [how to use Perl's rename on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75214132/how-to-use-file-rename-aka-perls-rename-in-windows/75214133#75214133)
- on Solaris, no `rename` command exists
- on macOS, the Homebrew packages `rename` and `util-linux` conflict
- on macOS, the Homebrew package `rename` offers a Perl script that looks different from the others
- on Arch Linux, the `perl-rename` package offers a Perl script that's also different from the others
- on Feroda, the `prename` offers a Perl script that's also different from the others
- on Debian, `prename` and `file-rename` are alternatives for `rename`
- on Ubuntu, `file-rename` is the only alternative for `rename`
- [mksh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mksh) has a builtin `rename`. To use Perl's `rename`, it is necessary to either use full path: `/usr/bin/rename`, or define an `alias rename=/usr/bin/rename`

#### Generic Perl `CPAN` install with or without root privileges

**I recommend this way, since there're too many different versions around. This way, you know exactly which version you will have.**

- use `cpan -i File::Rename` (Better use [perl brew](https://perlbrew.pl/) for regular user). The `rename` command will be available. If not, your `PATH` does not include Perl script utilities.
- for `Debian*`, use `dh-make-perl --build --cpan File::Rename` to make a Debian package

If you can't install anything, [download it](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sputnick-dev/perl-rename/master/rename) as a standalone script (simplified old version with no dependencies (except `perl`) and less switches than the newer versions)

### Mapping `rename` VS distros if not the good one

**If you prefer your system package manager:**

This is the default `rename` command on Debian (alternative) like OS (unlike Arch Linux, `rpm`-based distros, Slackware and *BSD).

- `rpm`-based distros:

  ```
  dnf install prename
  ```
- Arch Linux/Manjaro:

  ```
  pacman -S perl-rename
  ```
- Gentoo:

  ```
  emerge dev-perl/rename
  ```
- NixOs:

  ```
  nix-env -i perl5.36.0-rename
  nix-env -iA nixos.perlRename
  ```

This is [not the recommended way](https://stop-using-nix-env.privatevoid.net/) for purists.

- *BSD:

  ```
  pkg install p5-File-Rename
  ```
- Alpine Linux (in branch `edge` of the `testing` repository, not used by default):

  ```
  apk add perl-file-rename --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/
  ```
- macOS:

  ```
  brew install rename
  ```
- Debian-like/Ubuntu:

  ```
  apt install rename
  ```
- Slackware: [`slackbuild`](https://slackbuilds.org/repository/15.0/system/rename.pl/)

### Documentation

- check [perl's doc about rename](https://metacpan.org/dist/File-Rename/view/rename.PL)
- [perldoc perle#character classes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Character-Classes-and-other-Special-Escapes) is a must read page to understand the shorts `\d`, `\w` `\s`... (PCRE, Perl, Python, PHP)

### Unicode

There's also a specific Unicode `rename` implementation: [`Unicode::Tussle`](https://metacpan.org/release/BDFOY/Unicode-Tussle-1.111/view/lib/Unicode/Tussle.pm)

If you have file with contiguous Unicode UTF8 characters like `AaaÃééZzz.mp4` the Unicode part will be ignored. One solution is to use the special switch for `unicode`:

> -u, --unicode [encoding]
>
> Treat filenames as perl (unicode) strings when running the user-supplied code.
>
> Decode/encode filenames using encoding, if present.
>
> encoding is optional: if omitted, the next argument should be an option starting with '-', for instance -e.

or if you have a (older) version without `-u`, you can do:

```
PERL_UNICODE=ASD rename -n 's/\B\p{Lu}/ $&/g' ./*.mp4
```

Check

```
perldoc perlrun | less +/PERL_UNICODE
```

### Security

To avoid possible *shell injection* (thanks [@Stephane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas?tab=profile)):

```
rename -n 's/.*//' '--e=system"uname"#.mp4'
Linux
```

Make it a habit to use: (the most portable)

```
 rename -n 's/.*//' ./*
```

or if supported:

```
rename -n 's/.*//' -- *
```

It will both prevent *shell injection* and treating files starting with `-` as a switch.
Try to rename a file like `rename -n 's/.*//' -foobar.txt`

Comment: (Coming from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/757503/367454). In Alpine Linux, there is a package `perl-file-rename`, but it is in the `testing` repository of `edge` branch and isn't installed by default. Furthermore, mksh has `rename` as a builtin. Quoting `man mksh`: _rename [--] from to (defer always, needs rename(2)) Renames the file from to to. Both pathnames must be on the same device. Intended for emergency situations (where /bin/mv becomes unusable); thin syscall wrapper._