# rename a filename replacing substring with a variable value

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a set of files with the following filename structure:

```
aa_bbbbb_cccccccc_dddddd.txt
```

I want to replace the third element `cccccccc` with the value of the variable `value` which I extract from the content of the file.

The values of the 4 components of the filename change, so I cannot replace using string replacement, but I need to replace based on the position of the substring I want to replace.

Any suggestion how to approach this using bash script only?

---

I cannot use rename. It does not seem to work in cygwin and, in any case, I cannot use string replacement. If we consider the "_" as a separator, I need to replace the third field with the value contained in a variable.

Comment: Thanks to show us a concrete example

Comment: How is the variable written in the file? Is the file in a structured document format such as XML or JSON?

Comment: What operating system are you using? What do you mean by "bash scripting only"? Does that mean no external tools at all? No `sed`, no `rename`, no `mv`?

Comment: I am using cygwin

Answer (score 1):

`bash` does have a splitting operator, the same awkward one as in ksh or in POSIX `sh`: the IFS-splitting that is performed (and most often unwanted) whem you leave a parameter expansion unquoted.

```
cmd $var
```

*does* split `$var` on `$IFS` characters (and also performs globbing), also known as the infamous split+glob operator.

Generally, you don't want that which is why you generally need `cmd "$var"`, and even `cmd -- "$var"` for those commands that accept options.

However here, you could use it to do the splitting on `_`.

With:

```
IFS=_
set -o noglob
parts=( $file'' )
```

`$file` is being split on `_` and the resulting parts stored in the `$parts` array¹.

Then you can do:

```
parts[2]=$value
```

To change the third part (in bash like in ksh but unlike most other shells, array elements indexes start at 0, so the 3<sup>rd</sup> element is in `${parts[2]}`).

And you can join them pack with `_`s with:

```
newfile="${parts[*]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Example of a file with `value` variable

```
value=xxx
```

Then, using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

```
file=aa_bbbbb_cccccccc_dddddd.txt
rename -n 's/^(.+?_.+?)_.+?_(.*)/${1}_foo_$2/' ./"$file"
```

Remove `-n` (aka `dry-run`) when the output looks satisfactory.

Comment: The OP has said that "The values of the 4 components of the filename change, so I cannot replace using string replacement". They probably want something like `rename -n 's/^(.+?_.+?)_.+?_(.*)/$1_foo_$2/' "$file"`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Bash parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-parameter-expansion):

- `${parameter##word}` removes the longest matching prefix pattern `word` from `parameter`
- `${parameter%word}` removes the shortest matching suffix pattern `word` from `parameter`

```
file="aa_bbbbb_cccccccc_dddddd.txt"
value="replace me"

suffix=${file##*_}  # dddddd.txt
prefix=${file%_*}   # aa_bbbbb_cccccccc
prefix=${prefix%_*} # aa_bbbbb

mv "$file" "${prefix}_${value}_${suffix}"
```

or a bit shorter

```
file="aa_bbbbb_cccccccc_dddddd.txt"
value="replace me"
prefix=${file%_*}

mv "$file" "${prefix%_*}_${value}_${file##*_}"
```