# Renaming ogg files starting with i-

Tags: rename

I have a directory with ogg file, and want to change file names starting with `i-`.

What can I do?  For instance, doing `rename 's/i-nuovi/nuovi/g' *` gave me

```
Unknown option: marino-barreto-cinque-minuti-ancora.ogg
Usage:
    rename [ -h|-m|-V ] [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] [ -e|-E perlexpr]*|perlexpr
    [ files ]
```

Something is wrong, but cannot track it down.  How can I ensure that I watch `i-` from the beginning?

Comment: There are a few `rename` implementations.  Which one are you using?  Have you tried `rename -e 's/i-nuovi/nuovi/g' ./*`?

Comment: The title says `-i`, but the body says `i-`.  The first could cause problems.  The second shouldn't.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem with the title.  I found out that some files started with `-` and `rename` interpreted that as an option.

Comment: Things are not very clear, what I know is that `rename` is version 0.20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different implementations of [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

Try

```
rename --version
```

and check my link

Then

```
rename -n 's/^i-nuovi/nuovi/g' -- ./*.ogg
#                              ^^
#                       end of parameters
```

If that doesn't work, just try:

```
rename -n 's/^i-nuovi/nuovi/g' ./*.ogg
#                              ^^
#                       that should helps
```

Remove `-n` (aka `dry-run`) when the output looks satisfactory.

Comment: How can I ensure the match starts from the beginning of the file?

Comment: Added `^` anchor, check new code.

Comment: @GillesQuenot at least with my version of Perl rename (*File::Rename version 1.30*), `^` doesn't match at the beginning of the actual filename when the glob pattern start with `./`, **unless** you add one of `-d, --filename, --nopath, --nofullpath`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't demand using rename tool, this can be easily done with bash native functions/built-ins:

*for-loop* and *parameter expansion* (use man bash and search for `Parameter Expansion` for more info):

```
for ef in $(ls i-*); do mv $ef ${ef#i-}; done
```

If your files contain white spaces in their names you can use IFS (bash builtin also):

```
old_IFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; for ef in $(ls i-*); do mv $ef ${ef#i-}; IFS=$old_IFS; done
```

Comment: Better `for ef in i-*; do mv "$ef" "${ef#i-}"; done` - see [bash pitfall #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). With proper quoting, there's no need to mess with `IFS`.

Comment: @steeldriver, I realy like your approach. I will definitely use it.