# How to rename all files of the same name to another name in all subdirectories

Tags: rename

I have a bunch of subdirectories with nested directories that have files with the name

```
output.txt
```

. I would like to rename all those files to

```
output_modified.txt
```

I tried

```
find . -type f -name "output.txt" -execdir rename 's/output\.txt/output_modified\.txt/' '{}' \;
```

but it gives the error

```
rename: not enough arguments
```

What arguments am I missing or is there a better way to do what I need?

Comment: You don't need to escape the `.` in the replacement text, as that is not interpreted as RegEx.

Comment: Probably what you're missing is [What are the different versions of the rename command? How do I use the Perl version?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-are-the-different-versions-of-the-rename-command-how-do-i-use-the-perl-ver) - you are trying to use the Perl file-rename syntax, but likely have the `util-linux` implementation

Comment: @steeldriver Oh I see. I don't know bash very well. I actually had chatGPT generate that line for me :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `rename` here, just do:

```
find .  -name output.txt -type f -execdir mv -T output.txt output_modified.txt ';'
```

The `-T` is a GNU extension. Without it a `mv output.txt output_modified.txt` could rename `output.txt` to `output_modified.txt/output.txt` if there was already a directory called `output_modified.txt`.

Here `rename` could be useful in that it can rename more than out file at once, so could make it more efficient than calling one `mv` per file, but you'd need:

1. to [make sure your `rename` is one of the perl-based ones](/q/730894), not the dumb one in `util-linux`. It's sometimes called `file-rename` or `prename` or `perl-rename`.
2. Invoke it as:

   ```
   find . -name output.txt -type f -exec rename '
    s|\.txt\z|_modified.txt|' {} +
   ```

With the `{} +` form so `find` passes more than one at a time to `rename`.

Some variants of perl-based `rename`s can also take the list of files to rename NULL delimiited on stdin, so with those, you could also do:

```
find . -name output.txt -type f -print0 |
  rename -0 's|\.txt\z|_modified.txt|'
```

Answer (score -1):

IMO rename, find, etc. are confusing and hard to use. I find this type of thing easier with `mv`, https://github.com/sharkdp/fd and GNU Parallel.

```
fd output.txt | parallel --dry-run mv {} {.}_modified.txt
```

`parallel` runs the command you give for each line of whatever you pipe in (in this case `fd` will give a list of paths). `{}` means "the current input". `{.}` means the current input, but with extension removed. `--dry-run` will just print the commands that `parallel` would run, without seeing them. You should run this first, and then run without the `--dry-run` once you are satisfied.

You do have to install fd and parallel from your package manager.