# Bulk rename directories with spaces

Tags: bash, regular-expression, rename

I have a bunch of files and directories containing white spaces (several of them in each file name) and I'm trying to remove them. I am plagged with the 'dumb' `rename` that does not understand regex. So far I end up with something like

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | perl -pe 'print $_; s/\s+/_/g' | xargs -n 2 -0 mv
```

trying to combine the power of `find` (for now I wanted to rename only the first level of directories; I tried to circumvent the issue of `xargs` using spaces as separator with `-print0`) and of Perl regex.

It is going in the right direction (if I change `mv` by `echo` in the end I kinda get what I want) but it does not work completely.

Any generic suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: `perl -0` might help, you need the whole pipeline to produce and consume NUL separators. Look at the output from `perl` with e.g. `od -c`.

Comment: do you only have bash or would you also have zsh?

Comment: `perl -0` did the trick!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using `perl` already to generate the new names, just do the `rename` in `perl`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | 
 perl -0nE '$o=$_; s/\s+/_/g; rename $o, $_'
```

You could also use the new-fangled `/r` and do:

```
perl -0nE 'rename $_, s/\s+/_/gr or die "$_: $!\n"'
```

Comment: @roaima That is a good suggestion, but in this case the `-maxdepth 1` makes it unnecessary.

Comment: Good point. I should read more carefully

Comment: Yeah, but you probably want `-mindepth 1` as well, or maybe `-name '* *'`, or something to avoid matching `.` . What is this newfangled `/r` thing by the way?

Comment: @terdon, `/r` has the substitution **r**eturn the resulting value, instead of modifying the original. ([doc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer)) `perl -le '$a = "abc"; $b = ($a =~ s/.../xyz/r); print "$a $b"'` gives `abc xyz`

Answer (score 3):

You need the Perl's version of `rename`. Seems like you use `rename.ui`:

If you run:

and you have:

```
$ file -- "$(type -p rename)"
...ELF 64-bit
```

you have `rename.ui`.

If you have:

```
$ file -- "$(type -p rename)"
.../rename: Perl script text executable
```

it's Perl's rename.

Check in depth explanations about [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

Download or copy paste standalone [`rename`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sputnick-dev/perl-rename/master/rename)

Comment: Yes, I know about Perl `rename` and would definitely use it if available; as I said, I'm stuck with a distro where it is not available (and have no priviledged access to install it).

Comment: If you read my link, there's a standalone script that you can wget or just copy/paste. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sputnick-dev/perl-rename/master/rename

Comment: I may be tired: I did read your link but did not see the standalone `rename`. Thank you for pointing to the right script.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Perl anyway, why not do all of it in Perl?

```bash
perl -w -Mstrict -MFile::Find -E 'finddepth(sub { rename $_, s/\s+/_/gr }, ".")'
```

(The `-w` and `-Mstrict` options aren't necessary, but they're good practice as they enable warnings and strict mode.)

Note that the code above will happily rename files to a name that already exists, deleting the previous file of that name.  To avoid that, you can do e.g.:

```bash
perl -w -Mstrict -MFile::Find -E 'finddepth(sub { my $n = s/\s+/_/gr; rename $_, $n unless -e $n }, ".")'
```

Also, any errors from the `rename` will be silently ignored.  That's not particularly hard to fix either, but the code gets a bit verbose for a one-liner.  You could always write an actual Perl script, though, e.g. like this:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find qw(finddepth);
use Errno qw(EEXIST);

sub safe_rename {
  my($old, $new) = @_;
  $! = EEXIST and return if -e $new;
  rename $old, $new;
}

finddepth(sub {
  my $new = s/\s+/_/gr;
  return if $_ eq $new;
  safe_rename $_, $new or warn "Error renaming $_ to $new in $File::Find::dir: $!\n";
}, @ARGV);
```

If you save this script e.g. as `rename_space.pl`, you can run it with `perl rename_space.pl` (or just `./rename_space.pl` if you `chmod` it to make it executable) and pass the directories you want to process (e.g. `.`) as command line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `zsh` which has a `zmv` autoloadable function which can do batch renaming more safely and easily:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -n '*[[:space:]]*(#q/)' '${f//[[:space:]]##/_}'
```

Or recursively:

```
zmv -n '(**/)(*[[:space:]]*)(#q/)' '$1${2//[[:space:]]##/_}'
```

(remove `-n` (dry-run) if happy).

`zmv` does a few sanity checks including checking that two files are not renamed to the same file or that the destination files don't already exist before doing *any* renaming. It enables depth traversal by default.

It also skips hidden files by default. If you want to rename those as well, change the `(#q/)` (that selects files of type *directory*) to `(#qD/)` to enable `D`otglob for that one glob expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than thinking in terms of `find | perl | xargs`, it is often easier, cleaner and safer to loop over each file. The already renamed directory is a pitfall here, which is why the loop body is more than one line. This could be done in any language, but here is one in pure bash (save for the `mv` command):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
shopt -s nullglob globstar

for f in ./**/*' '*; do
    directory="${f%/*}"
    filename="${f##*/}"

    # The direcory would be renamed in a previous iteration
    # (because bash expands globs alphabetically).
    src="${directory// /_}/$filename"
    dst="${f// /_}"
    echo mv --no-clobber --no-target-directory -- "$src" "$dst"
done
```

Hint: Remove the `echo`  prefix once you are happy with what it would do.

This script only replaces spaces. To replace other whitespace, adjust accordingly. As commented, this could be augmented with `extglob`, but I'll stop here.

Comment: Note that the OP wants to replace  *all* sequences of whitespace with `_`, so that would be `${filename//+([[:space:]])/_}` (for which you also need `shopt -s extglob`)

Comment: As you make the assumption that directory components have been successfully renamed beforehand, you probably want to add a `|| break` to  abort the loop upon error so as not to end up moving files to separate directories.

Comment: Ah, `set -e` would handle that sorry.

Comment: Thanks for this elegant solution in pure bash; that is indeed a potentially better alternative of what I had in mind initially.