# Remove some chars from filenames recursively

Tags: bash, files

I have many files in folders and subfolders.

I need remove some chars (same position) from all filenames.

Example:

```
IMG-20230226-WA0002.jpg -> 20230226-WA0002.jpg
```

I think simple way is to use `echo ${i:N:N}`, so I did this.

```
for i in $(find . -type f); do mv "$i" "${i:5}; done
```

As I supposed, it shows me files with full path, so how can I do it correctly?

PS: And how can I do it for "string"? For example remove only string `IMG-` from files?

PS2: I don't want use `rename` command.

Thanks.

Comment: Renaming a file by removing a certain sized prefix is dangerous. For instance, if you run your `find` command again by mistake, file `20230226-WA0002.jpg` will now be renamed to `0226-WA0002.jpg`. I assume that's not what you need. Consider changing your question to how to remove a certain pattern from a beginning of the filename (like IMG-), for instance, if that's indeed what you want. Also, what's wrong with the `rename` command? Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use `rename`? Perl-rename is really one of the best tools for the job, is it that you cannot install it on your machine?

Comment: It's installable as regular user, if you care, check Perl's rename link that explains _in depth_ this in my answer.

Comment: You say "recursively" in your Subject line - is this a homework assignment that requires you to show you can use recursion? If not, do you really care if you get a recursive solution or not?

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
find . -type f -regextype egrep \
    -regex '.*/[[:alnum:]-]{7,}.*\.jpg$' -execdir bash -c '
        for file; do echo mv "$file" "${file:7}"; done
' bash {} +
```

I added `2: 5+2 = 7`, because the file start with `./`.

for strings:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -execdir bash -c '
    for file; do echo mv "$file" "${file#./IMG-}"; done
' bash {} +
```

or use `globstar` recursion:

```
shopt -s globstar

for file in **/*.jpg; do
   ( cd "$(dirname "$file")" && echo mv "$file" "${file#IMG-}" )
done
```

Remove `echo` statement if you are happy with the output.

---

If you change your thought about [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

```
rename -n -d 's/.*/substr($&, 5)/e' ./**/*.jpg
rename -n -d 's/^IMG-//' ./**/*.jpg
```

Remove `-n` switch, aka *dry-run* when your attempts are satisfactory **to rename for real**.

The `-d` switch rename only the file and discard file path.

---

`find`'s `-execdir` do a `cd` in the directory of the current file for each matches.

---

Don't use `for` loop to iterate over `find` to prevent shell *word splitting*.

Comment: Of course if there are some files with filename shorter than 4 characters, your first command would throw errors since the `mv` commands for those short named files would only get one argument. But that's also part of the question's problem.

Comment: OP can sanitize input files with `find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*/[a-zA-Z]{5,}'`. Added to first solution.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `mmv` tool. It should be in any modern distro and can do exactly what you want.

Example here would be

`mmv 'IMG-*.jpg' '#1.jpg'`

To remove the first 4 characters:

`mmv '????*.jpg' '#5.jpg'`

Comment: And for the first use-case?