# how to rename multiple files in multiple folders

Tags: debian

how i can rename USB-(DOT4)- to USB-DOT4- i am using debian 10 i have tried so many commands nothing working i have several files inside sub-folders with similar word please help

i have tried the following commands

```
grep -RiIl 'search' | xargs sed -i 's/(USB-DOT4)/USB-DOT4/g'
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/(USB-DOT4)/USB-DOT4/gI' {} \;
grep -rli '(USB-DOT4)' * | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/(USB-DOT4)/USB-DOT4/g' @
sed -i 's/-(USB-DOT4)-/-USB-DOT4-/g' *.exe
mmv USB-DOT4\* Installer\#1
mmv '*(USB-DOT4)*' '#1USB-DOT4#2'
rename 's/(USB-DOT4)/USB-DOT4/g' *
```

Comment: You say you want to *rename `USB-(DOT4)-` to `USB-DOT4-`* but all your attempts seem to want to rename `(USB-DOT4)` to `USB-DOT4`. Which is it?

Comment: in which way are the ones similar? What do they have in common, what's the factor that should make you decide you want to rename them? Are there also `SCSI-{COMA5}` you want to rename to `SCSI-COMA5` for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

```
$ find . -type f -name '*USB-*' -print0 | rename -n -d -0 's/[()]//g'
# USB-(DOT4)-  =>   USB-DOT4-
```

Remove `-n` switch, aka *dry-run* when your attempts are satisfactory **to rename for real**.

Comment: Worth noting: perl rename can take filenames from stdin as well as on the command line, even NUL separated using the `-0` option.  So the "multiple directories" part of the question can be satisfied with `find . -type f -print0 | rename -n -0 's/[()]//g'`