# How to reuse matched value in bash globbing?

Tags: bash, wildcards

I was wondering whether it is possible to reuse whatever was matched in a path with globbing? (Just as it can usually be done with regex substitutions?)

I'm aware that there are other solutions for the following example, but I'm just using it as an example for what I'm asking:
Let's say have the files `file_1.txt, file_2.txt, ..., file_100.txt` in the current folder, and I'd like to rename them to `asdf_1_qwer.txt`, `asdf_2_qwer.txt, ..., asdf_100_qwer.txt`. Of course I could match them with `file_*.txt`, but can I somehow reuse whatever was matched in `*` for specifiying the target file name?

Comment: Can you show how you would want to do it? No, there is no equivalent to regex capture groups in the shell, but you can get close by saving things in variables. What would you want to save here?

Comment: I would use [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895): `rename -n 's/.*(\d+).*/asdf_${1}_qwer.txt/' ./file_[0-9]*.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no direct equivalent to regex capture groups in the shell, what you describe is usually done using variables. For example:

```
$ for f in file_*.txt; do
   number="${f/file_/}" 
   number="${number/.txt/}" 
   printf 'The number from file "%s" is "%d"\n' "$f" "$number"
done
The number from file "file_1.txt" is "1"
The number from file "file_2.txt" is "2"
The number from file "file_3.txt" is "3"
```

Or, using `sed` instead of [shell string manipulation](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
$ for f in file_*.txt; do    
    number=$(sed -E 's/^file_([0-9]+)\.txt/\1/' <<<"$f"); 
    printf 'The number from file "%s" is "%d"\n' "$f" "$number"; 
done
The number from file "file_1.txt" is "1"
The number from file "file_2.txt" is "2"
The number from file "file_3.txt" is "3"
```