# How to rename large number of randomly named file at one go?

Tags: linux, rename

In a directory I have large number of randomly named `'.wav'` files. For example

```
090913yui.wav
jiyafa123.wav
.
.
.
awe-6rt.wav
```

I want to change the file names to

```
file1.wav
file2.wav
.
.
```

and so on

Can anyone help me with how to do the same? I have only terminal access to the server. So need to do it through some command only.

Comment: Try `c=1; for f in *.wav; do mv -- "$f" "file$c.wav"; ((c++)); done`

Comment: might lose files if fileNNN.wav already existed (use `mv -n` or `mv -i`)... does the order matter at all?

Comment: Are they to just be renamed sequentially or is there a certain pattern to follow? Are there any existing files that are already named in that format?

Comment: @Aeronautix you really ought to provide that as an answer

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. See [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895) (usable in any OS and any shells, a must have in the toolchest):

```
rename -n 's/.*/"file" . ++$::c . ".wav"/se' ./*.wav
```

gives:

```
rename(090913yui.wav, file1.wav)
rename(jiyafa123.wav, file2.wav)
```

Or with zero padding:

```
rename -n 's/.*/"file" . sprintf("%.3d", ++$::c) . ".wav"/se' ./*.wav
```

gives:

```
rename(./090913yui.wav, file001.wav)
rename(./jiyafa123.wav, file002.wav)
```

Remove `-n` switch, aka *dry-run* when your attempts are satisfactory **to rename for real**.

Comment: In Alpine Linux, there is a package `perl-file-rename`, but it is in the `testing` repository of `edge` branch and isn't installed by default. Furthermore, mksh has `rename` as a builtin. Quoting `man mksh`: _rename [--] from to (defer always, needs rename(2)) Renames the file from to to.  Both pathnames must be on the same device.  Intended for emergency situations (where /bin/mv becomes unusable); thin syscall wrapper._

Comment: I provided this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-are-the-different-versions-of-the-rename-command-how-do-i-use-the-perl-ver/730895#730895 that goes in depth explaining the use of Perl's rename and how to install it everywhere.

Comment: If you use `mksh` (you are =~ 0.00001% in the world), then use the full path of Perl's rename executable.

Comment: Since this answer makes a rather general claim and the linked answer doesn't include the bit of information about mksh, this needs to be mentioned. I will comment on that article as well. P.S: How many people use a shell is irrelevant. It exists and is used.

Comment: Feel free to improve linked answer if you are picky

Comment: Technically, mksh being the shell of Android, it's on most of the  world's devices, though in practice it's not directly *used* by many users.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the filename globbing pattern `*.wav` matches all the names that you want to change, then you may possibly use the following loop to rename the matching names in the way you want:

```bash
n=1
for name in *.wav; do
    while [ -e "file$n.wav" ]; do n=$((n+1)); done
    mv -- "$name" "file$n.wav"
done
```

This iterates over all matching names.  For each name, it finds an integer `$n` such that the name `file$n.wav` does not already exist. It then changes the current name to that name.

Answer (score 1):

With zsh's zmv:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
n=0; zmv -n '*.wav' 'file$((++n)).wav'
```

Or to `l`eft pad the numbers with 0s to a width of 3 so the files get sorted by number in the output of `ls` and most other things:

```
n=0; zmv -n '*.wav' 'file${(l[3][0])$((++n))}.wav'
```

Remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy. It will check ahead of time if there are any potential conflicts.

If some files have already been renamed, you'd initialise `n` to the highest number value of already existing `file<number>.wav` files and change the `*.wav` pattern to `(^file<->).wav`.