# rename files's name in linux

Tags: rename

I need to rename 3028 files' names at once.  Do you have any help?

```
0001____z1.0.tif    -->  0001.tif
0002____z2.0.tif    -->  0002.tif
   .
   .
   .

3028____z3028.0.tif --> 3028.tif
```

Can i rename whtout "`____z2.0.tif`" all files at once using the "rename" option for linux? or other way....? Please let me know if you have any idea. It would be grateful...

Comment: 'using the "rename" option for linux' – Warning: *the* `rename` is not well-defined. See [*What's with all the renames: `prename`, `rename`, `file-rename`?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/108618) and [*What are the different versions of the `rename` command? How do I use the Perl version?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/730894/108618)

Comment: I wrote an answer here about a similar question, I hope it can help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/759073/541313

Answer (score 0):

Using perl `rename` or `prename`:

```
rename 's/_.*/.tif/' *.tif
```

Comment: `sudo apt install rename` if you are on a debian-derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is already an answer, I believe this task can be accomplished with just the shell.

**Bash**:

*The expressions between the curly brackets are called [brace expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion)*.

```bash
for fn in {1..3028}; do
    mv "$(printf "%04d\n" "${i}")____z${i}.0.tif" "${i}.tif"
done
```

**POSIX**:

```sh
i=0

while [ "${i}" -le 3028 ]; do
    mv "$(printf "%04d\n" "${i}")____z${i}.0.tif" "${i}.tif"
    i=$((i + i))
done
```

You may need to change into the directory where the files are or add its pathname to the arguments of the `mv` command. For example, if the files are in `/tmp`:

```sh
mv "/tmp/$(printf "%04d\n" "${i}")____z${i}.0.tif" "/tmp/${i}.tif"
```