# How do I rename multiple Linux files using a bash script

Tags: linux

I have

```
123myfile123.jpg
123456myfile567.jpg
```

I would like to remove everything up to the first alpha char

```
myfile123.jpg
myfile567.jpg
```

I have this which remove all 0-9

```
mv '123myfile123.jpg' $(echo '123myfile123.jpg' | sed -e 's/[0-9]//g')
```

The result `myfile,jpg` I need `myfile123.jpg`

Any help much appreciated on this one.

Comment: Use for example a `sed` regular expression that matches the start of line character `ˆ` and any number of occurrences  of a  number with  `[0-9]*`  to strip only the leading numbers i.e something like `sed s/^[0-9]*//`

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion. There are probably more efficient ways to do that, but I hope it will help you...

```bash
for i in $(find . -type f -name '*.jpg'); do mv -v $i $(echo $i | sed 's/\.\/[0-9]\+\(.*.jpg\)/\1/g'); done
```

**Just a little explanation for the command:**

We first loop over each result of the `find` command, which matches every `.jpg` file.

Sample output:

```
./123myfile567.jpg
./123456myfile567.jpg
```

Then the `\.\/[0-9]\+\(.*.jpg\)` regex does the following job:

- I match the `./` at the beginning.
- I match one or more `[0-9]`, using the `+`
- I select the part I wanna keep using `()`, and call it later as `\1`

**[EDIT]**

There is also a [tool](https://www.howtogeek.com/423214/how-to-use-the-rename-command-on-linux/) called `rename` and also based on regex usage. I hope it will help some people.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `rename`, the Perl version by Larry Wall.

It can be installed in Ubuntu from the repository universe. (`getpack` is now own shellscript and can be added (or linked to) here if you wish.) I think you can install `rename` also in other Linux distros.

```
$ getpack rename
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 jan 10  2023 /usr/bin/rename -> /etc/alternatives/rename
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 jan 10  2023 /etc/alternatives/rename -> /usr/bin/file-rename
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4529 okt 31  2021 /usr/bin/file-rename
-------------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/bin/file-rename: Perl script text executable
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 package: /path/program  [for command 'rename']
 rename: /usr/bin/file-rename 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
type: rename is /usr/bin/rename

$ apt-cache policy rename
rename:
  Installerad: 1.30-1
  Kandidat:    1.30-1
  Versionstabell:
 *** 1.30-1 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

---

```
sudo apt install rename
```

---

Then you can check with a 'dry run' using the option `-n`

```
$ rename -n 's/^[0-9]*//' *myfile*.jpg
rename(123456myfile567.jpg, myfile567.jpg)
rename(123myfile123.jpg, myfile123.jpg)
```

and when it looks good remove `-n` and do it, rename the files.

**`rename 's/^[0-9]*//' *myfile*.jpg`**

The target files `*myfile*.jpg` should be modified according your actual target files, maybe simply `*.jpg`.