# How do I change the extension of a long filename quickly?

Tags: shell, cut, mv

original file: `a really really long name with spaces.ext`
target file: `the same name.new-ext`

command: `mv *part of the name that'll give a unique answer.ext $(echo $(ls -l | grep -i *.ext | cut -d ' ' -f 11-))`

result: `mv: target 'last word of the name.ext': No such file or directory`

What am I doing wrong?

PS: the remote machine only allows `sh` (not even bash) so tab-completion is out of the picture.

Comment: can you copy and paste with a mouse?

Comment: did you run your code through shellcheck per the shell tag description? you aren't quoting your arguments properly and note that `grep -i *.ext` probably doesn't do what you intend

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
for f in *long*.ext; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.ext}.new-ext"; done
```

Or in several shells including dash and busybox ash (not hush), where `$_` expands to the last argument of the previous command:

```
echo *long*
```

Check that it shows the right file, then:

```
mv -- "$_" "${_%.ext}.new-ext"
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of spaces in `ls -l` output before the filename varies a lot and usually isn't 10. The number of characters also varies so `cut -c` isn't safe either.

But you don't need `ls` at all (and shouldn't want `grep -i` because that would take e.g. ExT instead) -- just `$(echo *blah.ext |sed s/ext$/new-ext$/)` would work.

(corrected) Even better in bash/ksh/zsh I would do `f=(*ext); mv -- "$f" "${f%.ext}.new-ext"` and consider inserting a safety check for `${#f[@]} -gt 1`. If stuck on POSIX (e.g. dash, ash, busybox) could use `set -- *blah.ext; if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then mv -- "$1" "${1%.ext}.new-ext"; else echo>&2 "error: $# files match"; fi`.

Comment: note that posix shells support sourcing functions and executing scripts, so there's no reason to try to write a one-liner instead of clear/reusable/boring code. Since you are checking errors, don't forget handling when the destination already exists.

Comment: @jhnc: I think `$var` and `${var-edited}` is about as clear as you can get; do you have a better alternative? If you're repeating _anything_ fairly often, a script or function is worth considering, but not for a single use, and this Q doesn't say either way.

Comment: But once you add any sanity checks the chances of mistyping the line (`sh` may not enable any line-editing beyond erase and kill) rises rapidly. Much more chance to mistype than `change-ext -i "ext" "new-ext" glob-that-selects-relevant-files` or somesuch. Personally, I just start `vi`, `!!ls glob`, do any edits, then pipe to sh, but it's possible the remote system doesn't even have an editor.

Comment: @jhnc: simple (scalar) assignment is POSIX but doesn't glob. If run in process substitution (or more generally in a pipe) `ls *ext` does exactly the same as `printf '%s\n' *ext` for files but is wrong for subdirectories unless you add `-d`, and checking for multiples i.e. ambiguity is _more_ complicated which you already complaineda bout.

Comment: yeah, I should have [checked](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01): no pathname expansion. not sure what command I must have run yesterday that made me think it did

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to make use of the `rename` command:

```
rename '.old' '.new' *'long'*'.old'
```

We are using quotes as any of the strings could contain spaces.

Comment: `*'long'*'.old'` ?

Comment: Please be aware of the [different rename commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/730895/123460).

Comment: @jhnc There is no need for quoting of the shell pattern.

Comment: it you needed to quote `'.old'`, then you also need to quote it the second time. Similarly I am assuming `long` represents an arbitrary string (so could contain whitespace, etc)

Comment: @jhnc you are absolutely correct!