# Rename directories by removing part of a dir name

Tags: linux, directory, rename

Have lot of directories like the following

```
./parent/inventory_control-8118c470fa3811ed9add1fef7e5ef70f/snapshots/automation
./parent/configuration_data-6be54fa0fa3e11ed9add1fef7e5ef70f/snapshots/automation
./parent/zip_code-940ac1d0fa3f11ed9add1fef7e5ef70f/snapshots/automation
```

I would like to rename the directories by removing hypen and uuid from the directory name. The desired output is

```
./parent/inventory_control/snapshots/automation
./parent/configuration_data/snapshots/automation
./parent/zip_code/snapshots/automation
```

Can you please suggest a one line command to find all the directories and rename them? or a bash script as well can help.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried, and where you're getting stuck?

Comment: Is the part to be removed always a dash followed by a 32 hex character sequence at the end of a directory name?

Comment: Why must it be a one line command? Do you really value brevity over readability?

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. See [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for f in ./parent/*; do mv "$f" "${f%%-*}"; done
```

(bash)

Comment: It worked and a simple solution.

Comment: @Saravanan please remember to accept the answer with the ✓

Answer (score 2):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895) (usable in any OS):

```
rename -n 's/-*//' ./parent/*/
```

or

```
rename -n 's@-[[:xdigit:]]+/snapshots/@/snapshots/@' ./parent/*/snapshots/
```

Remove `-n` switch, aka *dry-run* when your attempts are satisfactory **to rename for real**.

You can add 32 hex condition if that's makes sense:

```
rename -n 's@-[[:xdigit:]]{32}/snapshots/@/snapshots/@'
```

Answer (score 2):

With the zsh shell:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -n '(**/)(?*)-[[:xdigit:]](#c32)(#q/)' '$1$2'
```

(remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy)

- `autoload` marks the `zmv` function as *autoloadable* which means that upon first invocation, the code of that function will be loaded from some file in one of the `$fpath` directories. With `-U`, alias expansion is not done upon that loading, with `-z`, it's loaded in *zsh emulation*, that is with a default set of options. Both safeguards to avoid customizations affecting the behaviour of that function. If you're using that function often, you may want to add that line to your `~/.zshrc`.
- `zmv 'pattern' 'expression'` finds files matching the *pattern* and renames it based on the result of the *expression*
- `(**/)`: matches and level of directories and captures it in `$1`.
- `(?*)`: at least one character, captured in `$2`.
- `[[:xdigit:]](#c32)` a `c`ount of `32` he`x`adecimal `digit`s
- `(#q/)` a `q`ualifier that restricts the match to files of type *directory*.
- `$1$2` computes the replacement.

`zmv` processes the files depth-first so if there's a `dir/a-FeedADeadBeef654321BadFadedDecaf/b-11112222333344445555666677778888` directory, `dir/a-FeedADeadBeef654321BadFadedDecaf/b-11112222333344445555666677778888` is renamed to `dir/a-FeedADeadBeef654321BadFadedDecaf/b` first and then `dir/a-FeedADeadBeef654321BadFadedDecaf` to `dir/a`.

It also does all the substitutions first and checks for conflicts before starting to do the renaming, to avoid losing data.