# Rename multiple files in directory - Using sed or rename command

Tags: linux, bash, sed, rename, mv

I have tried so many different `sed`, `mv` and `rename` commands - still I cannot rename these files. There are 50 plus files -  I tried commands I found - Help thx

Original filenames:

```
PAGES_TEST1_SART1.XML
PAGES_TEST2_SART2.XML
PAGES_TEST3_SART3.XML
PAGES_TEST4_SART4.XML
```

To

```
PAGES_PROD1_SART1.XML
PAGES_PROD2_SART2.XML
PAGES_PROD3_SART3.XML
PAGES_PROD4_SART4.XML
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which `rename` are you using?  With

```
$ rename --version
rename from util-linux 2.39.3
```

Starting with:

```
$ ls -1
PAGES_TEST_SART1.XML
PAGES_TEST_SART2.XML
PAGES_TEST_SART3.XML
PAGES_TEST_SART4.XML
PAGES_TEST_SART5.XML
PAGES_TEST_SART6.XML
PAGES_TEST_SART7.XML
PAGES_TEST_SART8.XML
PAGES_TEST_SART9.XML
```

You can do:

```
$ rename TEST PROD *
```

and get:

```
$ ls -1
PAGES_PROD_SART1.XML
PAGES_PROD_SART2.XML
PAGES_PROD_SART3.XML
PAGES_PROD_SART4.XML
PAGES_PROD_SART5.XML
PAGES_PROD_SART6.XML
PAGES_PROD_SART7.XML
PAGES_PROD_SART8.XML
PAGES_PROD_SART9.XML
```

Comment: too easy mate for my brain  -I ve been trying sed mv etc ,, thx so much this is great !!

Answer (score 2):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895) (usable in any OS):

```
rename -n 's/TEST/PROD/g' ./*TEST*.XML
```

Remove `-n` switch, aka *dry-run* when your attempts are satisfactory **to rename for real**.

Comment: Hi thx for ur reply  -  i tried this and it does not work   rename 's/TEST/PROD/g' ./*TEST*.xml - there is a 1 2 3 4  -- please look above - I forgot to put that in the name of the files - does that make a difference to ur commnd?

Comment: You provided files with UPPERCASE `XML` extension. Unix* are case sensitives

Comment: the command u shared does not work upper case aside I checked all that before responding to that _ I hope u can amend it

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something along this line (for bash):

```bash
for f in \`ls | grep PAGES_TEST\`; do mv $f $(echo $f | sed 's/TEST/PROD/'); done
```

Note the back ticks.

Comment: If you want to use a bash shell loop, I'd suggest something more like `for f in PAGES_TEST*; do mv -n -- "$f" "${f/_TEST/_PROD}"; done` which avoids some [bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)

Comment: 'steeldriver's take on it is more robust and better, and should be flagged as a correct answer.

Comment: thanks this one works as well!!!  for f in PAGES_TEST*; do mv -n -- "$f" "${f/_TEST/_PROD}"