# Numbering files and restart for every folder in command line?

Tags: shell, command-line, rename

I use a little script to numbering files. I start it with a `thunar` custom action. This only works when all files are in the same directory. the new files name are `00001.ext` to `00005.ext` when I rename 5 files. `krename` has an option to restart for every folder.

When i have this

```
/path/to/folder1/file1
/path/to/folder1/file2
/path/to/folder2/file1
/path/to/folder2/file2
```

my script would create this

```
/path/to/folder1/00001
/path/to/folder1/00002
/path/to/folder1/00003
/path/to/folder2/00004
               ^
           folder two
```

What I want is

```
/path/to/folder1/00001
/path/to/folder1/00002
/path/to/folder1/00003
/path/to/folder1/00004
               ^
           folder 1
```

is there a command line tool that can rename the files and restart for every new folder?

Comment: This is the script i use at the moment

a=1
for i; do
 ext=${i##*.}
 new=$(printf "%05d.$ext" "$a")
 mv -i -- "$i" "$new"
 let a=a+1
done

Comment: Add this to you original post

Comment: comments suck for code blocks and anything that needs formatting, it's better to [edit] the information to your post. That's where people will look for it anyway.

Comment: anyway, looking at the post, I'm not exactly sure what the rule about moving files from one directory to another should be, nor can I tell how the scriptlet you posted in the comment would move them

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. See [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895) (usable in any OS):

```
rename -n 's!folder\d+/.*!sprintf "folder1/%05d", ++$MAIN::c!se' ./folder*/*
```

```
$ tree folder*
folder1
├── 00001
├── 00002
├── 00003
└── 00004
folder2
```

Remove `-n` switch, aka *dry-run* when your attempts are satisfactory **to rename for real**.

To go deeper:

you can capture `folder` with:

```
rename -n 's!([^/]+)\d+/.*!sprintf("%s1/%05d", $1, ++$MAIN::c)!se' ./folder*/*
```

to make it *dynamic*.

You can add more logic inside if needed, it's Perl code.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
n=0
(cd /path/to && zmv -n 'folder<->/*(#qDn.)' 'folder1/${(l[5][0])$((++n))}')
```

Note the `n` glob `q`ualifier so files are sorted numerically and for instance files in folder10 are renamed after those in folder9, not between those in folder1 and folder2 which you'd get with the default lexical ordering.

Remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy.