# Remove invalid characters from recursive Linux filesystem

Tags: linux, scripting, filesystems, rename, command

I have a huge filesystem full of folders/files using invalid characters.

I have found one command that almost does what I want and it came from this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40712263/how-to-remove-special-characters-in-file-names

The command in question is below.

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" $(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g'); done &
```

This removes everything that isn't alphanumerical, hyphen underscore, period (full stop) with an underscore.

I need to have this command ignore spaces and not replace spaces with an underscore.

I have tried variations such as this.

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" $(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._- ]/_/g'); done &
```

Where I have added a space into the [] but of course, it was never going to be that simple.

Essentially, unless the files/folders use alphanumeric, hyphens, underscores, spaces or period/fullstops, I want all other characters replaced with an underscore.

How would I modify the above command to ignore spaces as well as the other characters or is there a better way of doing this? The rename command does not work on this server unfortunately which has limited some of the other solutions I have found.

Comment: Note: possibly the characters are not invalid (so usually it is better to fix scripts to accept Unicode characters, and you should consider security implication by doing what you are doing (you may overwrite the same file, if files have different *unacceptable* characters on same position. Just consider what you are doing, you may risk to make thing worst. (or maybe not, but after a `mv` you lost information and so only backups (which you surely have) may bring back initial state.

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` and [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

```
find . -depth -exec rename -n 's/[^\w .-]/_/g' {} +
```

remove `-n` when happy with the output.

This is *recursive*, and:

`LESS='+/^ +-depth' man find`

> `-depth` Process each directory's contents before the directory itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `-` in a character class denotes a *range of characters*. By writing `.-`   you are saying "match every character starting with `.` and ending with  , which is no character at all because   comes *before* `.`.

In order to match a literal `-` character, you need to

- escape it: `\-`,
- place it first in the character class, or
- place it last in the character class.

So,

```sh
for file in *; do mv "$file" $(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._ -]/_/g'); done &
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome. Is there a way to make this recursive for the entire set of files and folders.

Comment: The only issue I am seeing is that folders are trying to overwrite themselves.

[root@box Folder]# for file in *; do mv "$file" $(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._ -]/_/g'); done &clear
[3] 8611
[root@box Folder]# mv: cannot move ‘Poland’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘Poland/Poland’

Comment: @JandP you can just ignore those messages, they're warnings. And, to make it recursive, if you are using `bash`, run `shopt globstar` and then `for file in **/*; do ...`. Unfortunately, that won't really work since `$file` will also contain the full path, so the renaming might fail because if a parent dir contains bad characters, those will also be changed by `sed` and the `mv` will be given a target dir that doesn't exist. Just use `find` instead.

Comment: You may wish to consider https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting and [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373) And of course you may want to use `mv -n` to prevent it from overwriting any files, if it just so happens that a transformed filename will match another